# skipping over scanf loops in c

Tags: c, scanf

I don't know why, when I run this, it skips the "how many pages in the book" `scanf` and goes straight onto the second loop "who is the author".

I'm sure this is something to do with whitespace, but I thought I accounted for this with the `getchar` at the bottom of the for loop.

**header:**

```
struct bookInfo{
  char title[40];
  char author[25];
  float price;
  int pages;
};
```

**.c file:**

```
int main()
{
  int ctr;
  struct bookInfo books[3]; 
  for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
  {
    printf("what is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
    gets(books[ctr].title);
    puts("who is the author?");
    gets(books[ctr].author);
    puts("how much did the books cost");
    scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
    puts("how many pages in the book");
    scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
    getchar();
  }

  printf("here is the collection of books: \n");
  for (ctr = 0; ctr <3; ctr++)
  {
    printf("book #%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
    printf("\nit is %d pages and costs $%.2f", books[ctr].pages, books[ctr].price);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to type the dollar sign `$`? You should always check the return value from `scanf` to verify that the call succeeded.

Comment: Using the debugger is your friend. Often, a much better friend than posting, since the debugger doesn't care that what you describe as the problem makes no sense in conjunction with the code you've provided (but readers of your post are likely to notice that detail).

Comment: thanks for that. the issue was forgetting the $ - how retarded haha. definitely wont make that mistake again

Comment: the function: `gets()` is no longer with us due to its' many faults.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()`

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
puts("how much did the books cost");
scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
```

to this:

```
printf("how much did the books cost: $");
fflush( stdout );
scanf("%f", &books[ctr].price);
```

Unless you intend for your user to type a `$` before the price, which would be annoying.  You don't need the leading blank in the format string, since `%f` tells `scanf` to skip over leading whitespace.

Secondly, **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`.  Ever.  In any way, shape, or form.  It *will* (not might, *will*) introduce a point of failure / major security hole in your program.  It was deprecated in the 1999 standard, and has been removed from the standard library as of the 2011 standard.  It is the programming equivalent of splicing live wires while standing in a shower.

Use `fgets` (which, unlike `gets`, will attempt to store the newline character in the target buffer if there's room) or `scanf` (with an appropriate precision in the conversion specifier) instead.

Comment: If understand correctly - `gets` is bad but `fgets` is not?

Comment: @i486: Correct.  `gets` does not know how big the target buffer is, and if the user types in more text that the buffer is sized to hold, then `gets` will happily write that extra text to the memory immediately following the target buffer, leading to all kinds of mayhem.  `fgets` allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to read from the input stream, making it a bit safer (obviously, you have to pass the right value, so it's not completely foolproof, but it's not the gaping security hole that `gets` is).  And as of the 2011 standard, `gets` is no longer supported.

Answer (score -3):

That is because gets() reads the line of text present in the current buffer.  and since the current buffer contains "What is name of author ?" it reads it.

If you display the contents of the struct members you can clearly observe this.

So I Suggest this
    Use

```
    char *temp;
    fgets(STDIN,temp);
```

before Loop begins.

This helps you

Comment: `gets` does not read from `stdout`, and `temp` doesn't point anywhere meaningful; the `fgets` call will most likely result in an access violation.

Comment: `fgets()` takes 3 arguments.